# C# Razor drop down list onchange selectedIndex undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I have define the following dropdown list

```
@Html.DropDownList("shareId", new SelectList(
                              ViewBag.shareUsernames,
                              "value", "text"), 
                              new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }}))
```

and the following jQuery script for callback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#shareId").change(function () {
        var myIndex = $("#shareId").selectedIndex
        var selValue = $("#shareId").options[myIndex].value
        $("#response").text = selValue
    });
</script>
```

I change the dropdown list value and catch the undefined error in myIndex assignment. When I use chrome debugger, I see the `$("#shareId").selectedIndex` is 1.

So why it cannot assign to `myIndex`? why `myIndex` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are mixing up javascript and jQuery. Use `this.value` like following.

```
$("#shareId").change(function () {
    $("#response").val(this.value)
});
```

Comment: Thanks !  #response is input text, therefore, the assignment should be $("response").val(this.value).